# How do I keep the Diablo-themed worker portrait in StarCraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

I was reading a couple weeks ago that a [Diablo-themed worker portrait](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/20407578) would be coming to SC2. I see it in game, but is there a way to keep it?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the documentation that you have linked:

> These events and items will only be available for a limited time, so
>   be sure to check them all out before they’re gone.

There is no way to enable again this portrait.